# jqueryUI autocomplete suggestions misplaced in Chrome

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm editing the entire post to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="./jQuery/jQueryUI/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery/jQueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/><br/>
    <div id="LoginLinkSearch" class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" />
    </div>
<br/><br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I was experiencing problems in other browsers, but I believe this is due to me using a bad CSS file for the jqueryUI.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem you are having http://jsfiddle.net/Mu2NY/. I think you may need to provide more context to the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce it under jsfiddle either, but I just set up this revised demo under the latest jquery/jqueryUI builds.

Comment: This still works correctly. Do you have any other CSS added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using zoom (i can see something similar only in this case), try ctrl+0